# configuring the 'Run/Debug' in intellij

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I"m using intelliJ IDEA 12.1.3 and I am having an issue setting up the run configuration for a spring-mvc project that uses a tomcat server.

I have the application server pointed at tomcat

[image: run/app configuration image]

when I try to `run` the application, I get [this](http://pastebin.com/va36Lazr) error message

Comment: It seems like there is a problem connecting to MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is the connection between your driver and db you are trying to connect to.
Having looked at your log I can say that there could be a number of reasons why it is occurring.

I'm assuming you have done your basics but just in case see if you can connect to your DB via IDEA Interface directly.

On your right side of IDE should be a vertical tab called "Database" see if your datasource loads up there. If it doesn't well that's the smoking gun right there otherwise keep reading below.

Here is a good blog that helped me diagnose my issue (mine happen to have been active for too long and cut out without me knowing):

http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2010/09/06/debugging-communication-link-failure-exceptions-in-connectorj/

Hope that works for you, if not I'll help out more.